# Combining two javascript codes

Tags: javascript

I am in the process of setting up conversion tracking in Bing. I usually push code 1 and bing UET via GTM to track phone calls. I would like to track two goals this time but I don't know how to combine them into one single code.

code 1:

```
`<script>
 window.uetq = window.uetq || [];
 window.uetq.push
 ({ 'ec':'Phone calls'});
 </script>`
```

code 2:

```
 `<script>
  window.uetq = window.uetq || [];
  window.uetq.push
  ({ 'ec':'chat leads'});
  </script>`
```

Your help would be much appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put them one after another?

Comment: remove the duplicated first line from code 2 ... then add the next two lines at the end of code 1 (excluding script tags of course)

Answer (score 0):

You should combine your `window.uetq.push` parameters in an array of objects.

```
<script>
 window.uetq = window.uetq || [];
 window.uetq.push
 ({ 'ec':'Phone calls'},{ 'ec':'chat leads'});
 </script>
```

Comment: This pushes an array of objects as a single item into `uetq`, instead of pushing multiple objects into the `uetq` array. **Edit**: I've removed my downvote, since you fixed your code.

Comment: Thanks guys, I try @Phrogz solution and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!window.uetq) window.uetq = [];
window.uetq.push({'ec':'Phone calls'});
window.uetq.push({'ec':'chat leads'});
```

Or, more simply, [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) can take multiple arguments:

```
if (!window.uetq) window.uetq = [];
window.uetq.push({'ec':'Phone calls'}, {'ec':'chat leads'});
```

Comment: I think the following solution doubled up the number. For example if we get two chat leads, it is showing as 2 chat leads and 2 phone calls. Maybe I should add OR to the code?      `if (!window.uetq) window.uetq = [];
window.uetq.push({'ec':'Phone calls'}, {'ec':'chat leads'});`